# skspritenode can't see added children

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

This for add four skspritenodes. For each node i add a child. Each big node is animated with an skAction with a FollowPath RepeatForever. Why i can't see the children sprite but only the big sprite ,even if i set children zpostion to 1.0?

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {


    SKSpriteNode *spriteBig=[[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [_worldNode addChild:spriteBig];

    SKSpriteNode *spriteChild=[[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    [spriteChild setZPosition:1.0];
    [spriteBig addChild:spriteChild];

}
```

EDIT

Sorry i have edited the answer due some typing errors

Comment: what is Ombra? and it is because you're not adding on the spriteChild. You should do [spriteBig.addChild:spriteChild];

Comment: Do you still have an issue after your changes?

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the `spriteChild` sprites to the node graph.

```
SKSpriteNode *spriteChild = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWith...];
[spriteChild setZPosition:1.0];

// FIXME: you need to add spriteChild, for example:
[spriteBig addChild:spriteChild];
```